# int pointer that points to a static char

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, static

Consider this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define main_arg int argc, char *argv[]

int main(main_arg)
{
    static char chr = '5' - '0'; // Dec 5
    int *p = &chr;               // 4 bytes pointer

    printf("Result: %i", *p);

    return(0);
}
```

---

```
Result: 5
```

Why do I have to declare `chr` as static in order to have appropriate value?
If I don't use static, `p` will read 4 bytes of total, where the next 3 will be "random". But If that one byte `chr` represents is located in a static memory, that doesn't happen?

Is that Undefined Behavior and the result is uncertain and it just happened like so, accidently (all the times I try) ?

Comment: *Is that Undefined Behavior and the result is uncertain and it just happened like so accidently ?* Answer: yes.

Comment: Static memory is weird.

Comment: You are trying to read `sizeof int` bytes from an allocated `char` variable. Since `sizeof int > sizeof char` by definition, this yields undefined behavior (by definition). The fact that you get the correct printout when declaring it `static` is mere luck (a matter of chance).

Comment: I would same the same.. If it could show different result at least once though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in some system, you code may not run, majorly because of alignment. in some RISC system, `char` can be aligned to whatever, but an `int` has to be aligned to 4 bytes, for example. in this case, if you try to dereference the pointer like this, some memory access protection mechanism may emit an interrupt, and the whole program will fail immediately.

in your case, assuming you run in Linux, with intel cpu, compiling with gcc, `chr` will reside in `.data` segment, and all the irrelevant part of it will set to 0 most likely.

but again, you are accessing memory in a wrong manner, everything is supposed to happen, since it's an undefined behavior.

to provide more information, if you delete `static`, and run that program in the above environment, the extra value you read is not "random", but it is random, literally. this is called `canary`. it's a memory protection mechanism to detect stack focused attack.

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a variable static,  It is allocated in the .BSS or .data and that area is all zeroed out, so even if you have initialized chr to 5, coincidentally all the bytes after and before the address of chr are zero

Here is a way to verify. (It could be different on your system)

```
(gdb) x/16w &chr - 16
0x601030:   0   0   0   0
0x601040 <chr.2180>:    5   0   0   0
0x601050:   0   0   0   0
0x601060
```

And here are the sections.

06:43:46 ~$ readelf -s a.out

```
53: 0000000000601030     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT   24 data_start
54: 0000000000601041     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 _edata
55: 00000000004005e4     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   14 _fini
56: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND printf@@GLIBC_2.2.5
57: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __libc_start_main@@GLIBC_
58: 0000000000601030     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   24 __data_start
59: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND __gmon_start__
60: 0000000000601038     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL HIDDEN    24 __dso_handle
61: 00000000004005f0     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   15 _IO_stdin_used
62: 0000000000400570   101 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 __libc_csu_init
63: 0000000000601048     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 _end
64: 0000000000400440     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 _start
65: 0000000000601041     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT   25 __bss_start
66: 000000000040052d    53 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 main
67: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  WEAK   DEFAULT  UND _Jv_RegisterClasses
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, and although this fact is by itself correct, this answer is wrong in its context!

Comment: Does it make sense now?

Comment: only data without initial value will reside in `.bss`. in this case, `chr` should reside in `.data`.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr you are right... apparently both data and BSS are zeroed... see update of my answer

Comment: This is not a proof IMHO. Also, it is still platform-dependent behavior, e.g., you'd get `0 0 0 5` on a big-endian platform. Let alone the fact that you have no guarantee that after that `chr` variable in memory there are 3 bytes at an accessible memory address. Using an `int` pointer in order to access the memory allocated for a `char` variable is still undefined behavior. If you're lucky, then it will trigger a memory access violation immediately. If you're unlucky, then you'll just get some unexpected value, which will "cause havoc" at a later point in the execution of your program!!!

Answer (score 3):

A char datatype is one byte.  You are using an integer point "int *P" to point to one-byte memory location of chr, but C will treat this as a four-byte location because it thinks it is a pointer to an int, which is four bytes in length. Based on your results of 5, evidently when you declare it as static, the location of chr just happens to be followed by zeros and therefore the result is just 5.  When it is not declared as static, it is on the stack and just picks up the different values in the memory following the location of chr.  Regardless, using *P references memory that it should not and will yield unpredictable results.

BTW, your sample declares the int* as "*P" (capital P) and references it later as "*p" (lowercase p), so this code would not run as is.

Comment: I know and I fixed this.

Comment: to add to Paul's statement, if you did a printf ("%d", foo & 0xff), it would work because you are not looking at the next three uninitialized bytes. Static just has it point to a different memory region where the memory has been initialized to zero.